# Adding Sitelinks Search Schema for a Website targeting multiple content

Tags: search, data-structures, schema.org, json-ld

I have 3 type content (type1,type2,type3)

My current search format link for each content are:

```
http://example.com/search?q=search&type=type1
http://example.com/search?q=search&type=type2
http://example.com/search?q=search&type=type3
```

or I can change it to this:

```
http://example.com/search?type1=search
http://example.com/search?type2=search
http://example.com/search?type3=search
```

this JSON-LD code is true?

```
"potentialAction": 
    [
      {
        "@type": "SearchAction",
        "target": "http://example/search?type1={search_term_string}",
        "query-input": "required name=search type 1"
      },
      {
        "@type": "SearchAction",
        "target": "http://example/search?type2={search_term_string}",
        "query-input": "required name=search type 2"
      },
      {
        "@type": "SearchAction",
        "target": "http://example/search?type3={search_term_string}",
        "query-input": "required name=search type 3"
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### `query-input` and `target`

The value of the `query-input` property has to be the name of your placeholder (as suffix to `required name=`) as specified in the `target` value.

For the `target` value `http://example/search?type1={search_term_string}`, the placeholder is (indicated by `{` and `}`): `search_term_string`.

So instead of `required name=search type 1`, you have to use `required name=search_term_string`.

#### Multiple `SearchAction`

From the perspectives of Schema.org, it’s fine to provide multiple `potentialAction` values of the type `SearchAction`.

But for Google’s Sitelinks Searchbox, note that [their documentation says](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/sitelinks-searchbox#guidelines):

> Always specify one `SearchAction` for the website, and optionally another if supporting app search.

The rich result only features *one* search box, but you specify three `SearchAction` items. It’s undocumented what’ll happen in such a case (e.g., Google could decide to use always the first one, or none at all).